# Passing a command with whitespace to an Upstart service instance

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I have an Upstart service that is supposed to launch multiple worker instances (using [rq](http://python-rq.org/) as a job queue). But I'm having trouble passing commands with whitespace to the service launcher.

My Upstart config (worker-manager.conf) looks like this:

```
description "my worker manager"

instance $id

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

script
    logfile="/home/ubuntu/worker.log"
    exec bash -c $cmd 2>$logfile
end script
```

So, to start the worker, this works:

```
sudo service worker-manager start id=1 cmd="rqworker"
```

But this doesn't:

```
sudo service worker-manager start id=1 cmd="rqworker -v queue_1"
```

The error I get is:

```
start: Env must be KEY=VALUE pairs
```

I haven't had any luck yet using double quotes, single-inside-double quotes or escaping the whitespace either. Hardcoding the argument inside the config file does work.

I can't pass the command in as multiple arguments, because I don't know in advance which or how many queues should be listened to etc. 
The workaround I have at the moment is to put the command in a file and let the service manager read it from there, but that's messy and I'm sure there's a better way. Also, this is all supposed to be happening on a bunch of AWS "minion" instances controlled by a master, so that limits the number of solutions open to me. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `start` command directly

```
sudo start worker-manager id=1 cmd="rqworker -v queue_1"
```

though you may need to quote again:

```
sudo start worker-manager id=1 cmd="'rqworker -v queue_1'"
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! As you suspected, I had to wrap my $cmd variable in quotes in my exec line, i.e. `exec bash -c "$cmd" 2>$logfile`, but with that done, it works!

Answer (score 1):

U can try exporting cmd variable before sudo command.

It might work

```
export cmd="rqworker -v queue_1"
sudo -E service worker-manager start id=1
```

You need to read man sudo carefully, and pay attention to the -E flag. This might work